# Meaning of following sed lines used in bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I recently come across the following line in a bash script

```
sed -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;ba' -e '}' | sed -e '$s/,$/\n/'
```

input to the first part of pipe is given by another pipe and input is of the form 
`1,2.3,2.453,23.5345,`

Comment: It means you have to hope that @Jotne, Kent, anubhava, glenn jackman, or Ed Morton read this :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell - or Floris… :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell EdMorton would just point out that's a ridiculous use of sed in the first place ;-). If your sed script uses more than s, g, and p (with -n), it should've been done in awk so no-one has to decipher hieroglyphics like that. Thanks for the nod though.

Comment: I'm off to bed smiling broadly and shall attempt to read Floris after a strong coffee in the morning :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @EdMorton you are absolutely right that `sed` is not the tool for this job - but this was such a cryptic expression I just _had_ to figure it out...

Comment: Thanks, noted these names: Jotne, Kent, anubhava, glenn jackman, or Ed Morton, and MarkSetchell or Floris. Easily for me to follow now, their answers normally are very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite the expression. Let's try to pick it apart. The first few commands are

```
sed -e     invokes `sed` with the `-e` flag: "expression follows"
:a         a label - can be used with a branch statement (think "goto")
'/\n*$/    any number of carriage returns followed by end of string
{$d;N;ba'  delete the last line; next; branch to label a
-e '}'     close the bracket
```

This can really be thought of as the one-line equivalent of a sed script file:

```
:a         # label a 
{          # start of group of commands
/\n*$/     # select a line that has carriage returns and then end of string
           #(basically empty lines at end of file)
$d;        # delete the last line ($ = last line, d = delete)
N;         # next
ba         # branch to a
}          # end of group of commands
```

at the end of this we have no empty lines left at the input. You can test this with a file that has empty lines at the end - you will find that when you run it through this first part of the script, the empty lines are gone.

Now let's look at the second (easier) bit:

```
sed -e     invoke sed on the output of the previous command
'$s        substitute in the last line
/,$/\n/    a comma before the end of the line with a newline
```

In other words, the whole script seems to do:

> Remove all empty lines at the end of the input, then strip the comma at the end of the last line that was not an empty line and replace it with a newline

Comment: why do we need a goto type statement for stripping empty lines at the end?

Comment: @i_m_optional - I think it is because the script deletes _only the last line_. If there are multiple last lines, they are deleted one at a time.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to solve the riddle. If the OP posts some sample input and expected output I expect someone could provide a simple, clear awk script that does the same thing for him to compare.

Comment: @EdMorton - yes, I would like to see confirmation that my analysis is correct, and I'm sure that there are better ways to achieve this. I did just google "delete all blank lines at end of file" and found http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/sed1line.txt which includes exactly (*verbatim*)the first part of this riddle (search `delete all trailing blank lines at end of file` in the page). This makes me feel quite a bit better.

Comment: I just posted an awk script that'd do the same thing you think the sed script does (and I'm sure you're right). Amazingly simple and obvious, of course. Most of that sed1line page should be replaced by the simple (possibly anti-Nike) statement "just don't do it".

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: this is NOT an answer to the posted question so do NOT accept it as such. This is just an awk script posted for comparison with the posted sed script in the question for some additional insight/information.

Assuming @Floris is correct on what he thinks the script does, here's one way to do it with GNU awk. The input file has a couple of lines of data and then 2 blank lines:

```
$ cat file
1,2.3,2.453,23.5345,
1,2.3,2.453,23.5345,


$
$ gawk -v RS=',\n+$' '{print}' file
1,2.3,2.453,23.5345,
1,2.3,2.453,23.5345
$
```

In the above `RS=',\n+$'` tells awk that there's only 1 record in the whole file and it's everything before the last comma followed by 1 or more newlines. The `{print}` prints that record, which could have been done with `'1'` as that's a true condition that'd invoke the default action of printing the current record, but I'm trying to emphasize the clarity part of conciseness over brevity in this one since I expect the OP is a newcomer to awk.

Comment: Ed - thanks for posting this. It is clear that `sed` is a powerful tool, but not always the best. `grep`, `awk` (and possibly `perl`) need to be in the toolbox of anyone that does a lot of text file processing. "Don't hit a screw with a hammer". Actually, I have heard "Manchester screwdriver" used as the derogatory term for a hammer... unsubtle but surprisingly effective on certain kinds of wood.

Comment: `sed`, `grep`, and `awk` are all excellent for their primary purpose. `sed` is `Stream ED`, i.e. a version of the text editor `ed` that works on streams of single lines and so is excellent for simple substitutions on singe lines. `grep` is the `ed` commands `g/re/p` for finding and printing lines from a file that match an RE and so is excellent at that. `awk` was created as a general purpose text manipulation tool/language and so is excellent for everything else that `grep` and `sed` don't do well. I haven't figured out a purpose for `perl` yet for text processing but YMMV I suppose.

Comment: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/108/EssentialPerl.html : *"Perl is probably best known for text processing -- dealing with files, strings, and regular expressions."* It has the most powerful set of regular expressions (certainly beats the socks off `sed`).

Comment: sed and perl aren't peers. awk and perl are peers for text processing. perl has additional functionality that makes it also a peer for shell. IMHO for text processing perl's a bloated, incomprehensible language for a tool that doesn't come as standard on all UNIX installations. It seems to have a lot of language constructs focused on slight improvements in brevity at the expense of huge sacrifices in clarity. I'm sure perl has it's uses, but best I can tell text processing isn't one of them when you have awk available on every UNIX installation and it's language facilitates more clarity.

Comment: Ed - I agree with you (which is why I had put `perl` in parentheses as a "maybe you also want this" option). The other three are the ones I use all the time; I occasionally see `perl` fanatics, and thought I would give them a nod...

Comment: Maybe http://www.zoitz.com/archives/13 says it best :-). Like I say, I'm sure perl has it's uses (it must since so many people seem to use it), I just haven't found one yet, but then I've only been programing in UNIX for 30 years so it's probably right around the corner :-). To be fair, I'd been fighting with shell+sed+grep+etc. for 10 years before I figured out awk was the right tool for general text processing so I may just be slow on the uptake and another 30 years from now will eat my words!

Comment: Good cartoon - looks like it was drawn by the xkcd fellow...?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114591/50517 - I am hoping we'll get our answer there!

Comment: No idea who drew it, someone else posted it in response to a different question and I bookmarked it. Looks like your question is about to closed. I particularly liked one posters response `perl combines the power of sed, awk, grep and tr. So, I would conclude perl is better than awk`. As-if awk itself can't do what sed, grep, and tr do. Sigh...

Comment: I would suggest not posting an "answer" which you know is a non-answer; there's too much of that already and this encourages the practice in less useful cases too. Rather, I would suggest for something like this that you post a comment with a link to the information you think will be helpful (such as http://ideone.com/x4Vzv7).